# How to display data in rows and columns and let user to add ,modify and delete them in runtime in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, excel, datagridview

I am developing a web application in asp.net.
In one of my pages I have a date control to the upper right which is of ajax control toolkit.
Now According to the date selected I want to display the date's other respective data(i.e. columns from database) in rows and columns.
I want the data to appear like in excel worksheet The user should allowed to add , modify and delete data in runtime and parallely those modifications must overwrite their original data in database and be stored there.
I am not using gridview because as i clearly said I want data like in excel worksheet.
Can this be done?? 
I saw an example of DataGridView control in windows forms.
 But I want it in aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript + ajax to replicate the changes on the fly. But for that you will have to build some custom functions that will increase the rows at runtime than post the changes through ajax in database....